# I made improvements to free code I found online and notified the author. Was this the right thing to do?

Tags: open-source, refactoring

I recently used a library from http://www.braemoor.co.uk/software/index.shtml (the EU VAT No validation library at http://www.braemoor.co.uk/software/vat.shtml) in a project at work. It mentions as the license (or something that looks like one):

> All software is provided as freeware for personal or commercial use without obligation by either party. The author will not accept responsibility for any problems that may be incurred by use of this software, although any errors reported will be corrected as soon as possible. Re-distribution of this software is NOT permitted without explicit permission.

I checked the code and found (and applied) a few ways to improve the code so it's more easily maintainable and more readable (you can find [one of them](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/57791/11074) on CodeReview.SE). After applying these changes, I considered that others might benefit from them as well and sent them as feedback to the author on his contact address. A few hours later, the author sent a reply thanking me for my suggestions, and that he would go over my changes and keep me informed.

My main concern is that while the website mentioned that it was freeware, I'm not sure how far I am allowed to go in altering his software without knowing the license. I assume it's license-free, but it's not specifically mentioned as open source, and I'm slightly worried that I might have overstepped my bounds and took too much liberty with the whole thing.

Did I do the right thing?

Comment: It's not clear what your question actually is.  Is notifying the original author a good thing to do?  Sure. Do you want to make additional changes for your own use? Go ahead, that's well within the terms of the freeware license.  The only thing prohibited is redistributing the code which you haven't asked about.

Comment: If you ever need to ask whether or not a copyright holder thinks that what you're doing with his code is OK, all you need to do is ask him, especially since you're already in contact with him.  That said, the license makes things pretty clear; you can do whatever you want with the code except redistribute it.

Comment: In theory, I think your employer might have a claim on the software?  If you used it at work and were developing some of your changes at work, depending on your contract, your employer might own your code.  The open source library can be used without obligation, but if you did some of it at work (or even at home, again, depending on your contract), there is a good chance you don't own that code - your employer does.  And they might want you giving it away.

Comment: I am not a lawyer. It depends on the copyright laws in you location, and possibly on contract law (a licence is a contract). In uk an ambiguous license is interpreted in favour of the party that did not write it. But of much more importance is the last sentence “Re-distribution of this software is NOT permitted without explicit permission.”

Comment: @Rob did you mean “And they might *not* want you giving it away”, if so then they must consider that giving away the 1% is cheaper than writing 100% and keeping it to them self.

Comment: @richard I assumed that "redistribution" here means that you cannot resell the code like it's from you, but it's fine to include it as a part of your (commercial) software product, becaus they mention "it's free for commercial use". We sell software as a service (basically hosting, development and support), mainly as extensions for a 3rd party product we're a licensed partner of, so I'd assume that it's okay to use this code in our product. I'll ask the author for clarification on this.

Comment: @richard - Sorry, yes, I meant 'not'.  The thing is, the company doesn't *have* to give away that 1%.  With this software, they could just use the freeware software, modify, and it use it themselves.  They might see a value in 'sharing', but a lot of companies are very protective of their work/work of their employees.  A competitor might benefit from those improvements - the company doesn't gain by giving them away.  If the license of the original project requires it, then yes, they have to in order to benefit from not starting over themselves...but here, it sounds like their choice.

Comment: @RobP. Yes this is correct for most Free Software or Open Source licences, it is not necessary to distribute changes. The only exception I Know of is AGPL (not GPL), then if you use the software on a server, you have to make the AGPL software available to those that have access to the server, that would include the changes. That is how you pay for the software. The FSF don't want your money, they just want you to love one another. If you can't love then don't use the software.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Legally, you're almost certainly fine (assuming the changes you offered are yours to offer).  The author provided the source, and shouldn't be surprised if people use it and/or improve on it.  The only reasonable restriction would be on distribution, and even that is probably not an issue in your case.  (But ask the author before you host the code somewhere, for example).

Ethically, in my opinion, there's nothing wrong with offering improvements to someone's code, as long as:

- they're within the project's intended scope;
- they work exactly as advertised (or as close to it as at all possible); and
- their addition to the project wouldn't subject anyone to any hidden or onerous license terms, or make the project incompatible with its own license.

If the change fixes bugs or improves maintainability without changing functionality, you definitely did the right thing.

Comment: I basically replaced a 100 line switch statement with a single line and 2 helper functions. I replaced a while nested in a for loop with a regular expression. neither change altered the code logically or fixed bugs, but they made the code easier to maintain.

Comment: @NateKerkhofs: If it's indeed a pure refactoring, sounds like changes i'd have recommended as well -- and welcomed if they were suggested to me.  Keep up the good work.  :)